# Need example of dojo portlet event(onSizeChange)

Tags: dojo

I'm using the `dojox/widget/Portlet` event called onSizeChange. However, it does not seem to be working. Below is my code.

```js
var portlet = new Portlet({
    id : 'dynPortlet_' + PorNum + "_" + data.vid,
    closable : true,
    title : '' + vidgetName,
    resizeChildren:true,
    content : portletContent,
    onSizeChange:function(widget){
       alert(widget);
    }
});
```

When moving the portlet, the onSizeChange event does not occur. Please help.

Comment: If you move a Portlet it won't change its size! So are you searching for an event that captures the move action or do you want to recognize when the size changes?

Comment: @MiBrock yes i want to recognize when Portlet size changes! but i don't know..advice to me! onSizeChange function is not working

Comment: have you tried onUpdateSize, in the source its listed as the function that is called on resize

Comment: @tik27 can i see example?? i want to see example to fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is: If you are just drag and drop the Portlet the size wont change and also your eventlistener onSizeChange wont do anything.

If you change the content of your Portlet ( add Data or remove ) the the size changes and your event gets called.

Have a look at this fiddle. I changed the dojo-example a bit so the content of Portlet1 changes to Zero. Size changed and the Eventlistener answers.

http://jsfiddle.net/BTBx4/

```
  dojo.require("dojox.layout.GridContainer");
  dojo.require("dojox.widget.Portlet");
  dojo.require("dijit.form.DropDownButton");
  dojo.require("dijit.TooltipDialog");

dojo.ready(function(){
// create a new GridContainer:
var gridContainer = new dojox.layout.GridContainer({
    nbZones: 3,
    opacity: .5,
    hasResizableColumns: false,
    allowAutoScroll: false,
    withHandles: true,
    dragHandleClass: 'dijitTitlePaneTitle',
    style: {width:'100%'},
    acceptTypes: ['Portlet'],
    isOffset: true
}, 'placeHere');
// prepare some Content for the Portlet:
var portletContent1 = [
    dojo.create('div', {
        innerHTML: 'Some content within the Portlet "dynPortlet1".',
        style:'background-color:#E0E0E0;border:1px'
    })
];
// create a new Portlet:
var portlet1 = new dojox.widget.Portlet({
    id: 'dynPortlet1',
    closable: false,
    dndType: 'Portlet',
    title: 'Portlet "dynPortlet1"',
    onSizeChange:function(){
    alert('I have changed');
    },
    content: portletContent1
});
// create a new TooltipDialog:
var tooltipDialog=new dijit.TooltipDialog({
    content: "Content for TooltipDialog",
    style: {width:'320px'}
});

var ton = new dijit.form.DropDownButton({
    label: "change",
    onClick: function(){
       portlet1.set("content","0");
    }

});
// add the DropDownButton to the Portlet:
  portlet1.addChild(ton);
// add the first Portlet to the GridContainer:
gridContainer.addChild(portlet1);
// startup GridContainer:
gridContainer.startup();
});
```